# "Zwar" ohne darauffolgendes "aber"?

Tags: style, particle

Stilistisch wird in argumentativen Texten mit der Partikel *zwar* eine Klammer geöffnet. Schon öfter bin ich jedoch über Texte gestolpert, in denen das schließende *aber* vergeblich auf sich warten lässt. Ein Beispiel von [heise.de](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Funkforschung-Schlaue-Sendetechnik-laesst-Modems-schrumpfen-3651773.html):

> Aktuell eignet sich der Chip zwar nicht für den Einsatz mit nah beieinander liegenden Up- und Downlinkfrequenzen.

An keiner Stelle im nachfolgenden Text folgt das erlösende *aber*, *jedoch* oder Ähnliches. Bei solchen Konstruktionen sträuben sich mir jedesmal die Nackenhaare wie bei einem Musikstück, das in einer unaufgelösten Harmonie endet. Sicherlich mag es Autoren geben, die diese Methode absichtlich anwenden, um beim Leser Unbehagen oder Gespanntheit zu erzeugen.

Mich interessiert jedoch, ob es eine offizielle Regel dazu gibt, dass auf ein *zwar* zwingend ein *aber* oder vergleichbares folgen muss. (Von den anderen Verwendungen wie *und zwar folgendes* mal abgesehen.)

Comment: Der Wunsch nach einem *aber* scheint der modernen Sprachempfindung geschuldet - Im Grimmschen Wörterbuch muss man den (seitenlangen) Eintrag zu *zwar* zur Hälfte durchblättern, bis man an Platz (6) der Bedeutungen das erste *aber* findet.

Comment: Ich frage mich was das "zwar" in dem Satz bringt.  Klingt besser ohne.

Comment: Solche Vorkommen von 'zwar' ohne Abschluss sind schlicht Textfehler, die vor der Veröffentlichung nicht korrigiert wurden – in Zeiten wo jeder unter Zeitdruck allein vor sich hintextet, Absätze  mehrmals umformuliert und Redaktionen sich ordentliche Korrekturleser sparen müssen ...

Comment: Man könnte ja den Autor direkt fragen. Bei Heise geht das ganz einfach per Mail.

Comment: @DictionaricsAninymous l guess you could post your  comment  as an  answer...

Comment: Eine weitere Fundstelle: *»Der weltgrößte Teilchenbeschleuniger, der Large Hadron Collider (LHC) bei Genf, hat zwar 2012 das Higgs-Teilchen entdeckt.«* [Spektrum der Wissenschaft: Wie schön ist das Universum?](https://www.spektrum.de/news/wie-schoen-ist-das-universum/1570712) (zwischen den Fotos von Steven Weinberg und Sabine Hossenfelder)

Answer (score 3):

Es war ein Textfehler. Das kann man daran erkennen, dass der Satz bei heise.de mittlerweile korrigiert wurde. Jetzt heißt er:

> Aktuell eignet sich der Chip jedoch nicht für den Einsatz mit nah beieinander liegenden Up- und Downlinkfrequenzen.

Das "zwar" wurde durch "jedoch" ersetzt.

Comment: In diesem Fall ist das relativ einfach ersichtlich. Ich hätte aber am liebsten eine feste Regel, die das "zwar ... aber" erklärt.

Answer (score 1):

Ein *zwar* bedarf auch nach meinem Sprachempfinden immer eines *aber*. Ebenso, wie zu einem *sowohl* immer auch ein *als auch* gehört.

Steht ein *zwar* alleine, ist das vermutlich der Textbearbeitung und mangeldem Korrekturlauf geschuldet.